# XML file change

Tags: xml, payment, bank

Will the bank accept an xml file that has been generated if I edit the date within the file? I had generated a file for the bank with the payment date as yesterday but it was never uploaded to the bank so now need to change the payment date to today to get the file uploaded.

Comment: It's a good question, but not for StackOverflow; it's not a question about programming, or even a question about XML; it's a question about your (unknown) bank's business policies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, it's about the business policy of a (unspecified) bank.